# Orientation of my app is ruining by pressing a back button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPad app which has a weird quirk. I'm using it inside a Navigation Controller and when I press on 'Back' on any screen other than the first screen it transitions to, it changes my orientation to portrait. For example...

Screen 1 >> Screen 2 - If I press back on Screen 2 there is no problem transitioning back to Screen 1.

Screen 1 >> Screen 2 >> Screen 3 - If I press back on Screen 3, Screen 2 renders in portrait, and then if I go back again, so does Screen 1.

In Xcode, I have it setup so that the app only supports right landscape orientation. I also have the following code:

```
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
        return YES;        
    return NO;
}
```

So what is happening when I press back on screen 3 (or later)? I don't understand why it is changing the orientation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure you got the exact same setup for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` implementations in **all** viewControllers.

Comment: Thanks, it was an oversight on my part. I hadn't linked some of the view controllers properly, hence they weren't hitting the method that defines only a right landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for all the screens

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my code didn't paste properly above. That's exactly what I have at the moment and it doesn't stop the weird orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in Project Settings?. It should look like this[image: Have you checked in Project Settings?. It should look likethis]

Comment: Yes I've got it so landscape right is in black and the rest aren't selected as I only want that orientation.